# Pass parameters in a sql script via java

Tags: java, sqlplus

I have a sqlplus script which requries some external parameters. Those parameters should come from an array present in the java code. I want to pass those values to the sql script but don't know how. Please guide me.

MY sqlplus file is as shown below

```
SET ECHO OFF 
SET HEADING OFF 
SET FEEDBACK OFF 
SET VERIFY OFF 
SET DEFINE ON 
SET TRIMSPOOL ON 
SET NEWPAGE NONE 
SET TERMOUT OFF
spool &3/&2..&1..fn
select text
  from dba_source
 where name = '&2'
   and type = 'FUNCTION'
   and owner = '&1'
 order by line
/
spool off
exit;
```

The java code I am using to execute this file in unix server is shown below.

```
try {
            String line;
            Process p = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(
                    "sqlplus -L user/pwd@SID @" + sqlFilePath);
            BufferedReader input = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(
                    p.getInputStream()));
            while ((line = input.readLine()) != null) {
                System.out.println(line);
            }
            input.close();
            p.destroy();
        } catch (Exception err) {
            err.printStackTrace();
        }
```

Please guide me how can I pass a string present in the java code to execute this sqlplus script in unix server.

**Edit : My Solution**

Created a temp file with the same query and replaced the parameters in it. Executed the temp file in the above code.

Comment: Did you think about generate the script from Java?

Comment: Why do you want to use Java for this? It's probably easier to use an interpreted language such as Python or , since you are on Unix, Bash script.

Comment: instead of running directly sql*plus, I'd run a shells script invoking the sql*plus (so I can have variable sostitutions) or better, I'd make a stored procedure.

Comment: Actually I have much bigger requirement which has to be done using java only. This is a small part of my entire requirement. Hence I have to execute this sqlplus script using java only and pass the parameters from java.

Comment: @Drumnbass Thank you for your suggestion. I created a temp file replacing the parameters and it worked fine.

Answer (score 0):

Try using a template engine like http://freemarker.org/. It is very generic, but should not be so difficult to use.